# Is there a Formal discipline of tying Logic Puzzles to Mathematical Equations?

Tags: logic

I am attempting to find the answer to a long standing question in mathematics, known as the Collatz Conjecture.

In this attempt, I’ve figured for myself, in a way that I haven’t seen produced anywhere else that I could compare to, that the initial conditions of the problem are similar to the structure of a specific, famous, difficult, Logic Puzzle.

That is, “The Hardest Logic Puzzle Ever”, and as a result the “Knights and Knaves” puzzle.

There are elements of the structure of both questions that I believe should be able to produce results in a similar fashion, whether or not they explicitly prove the initial Conjecture true.

I would like to dig further, and I want to know if there is a body of work for me to reference first, with terminology that I can use, before trying to prove this thing from the ground up?

Comment: Have you read much on Combinatorics? This sounds like the general field, though I don’t know much on the specifics of the puzzles you mention.

Comment: @PaulRoss I have not, but that looks to be the start of what I will end up having to read through.